# Our site using Akamai is returning 404 (from time to time)

Tags: linux, http, http-status-code-404

We are facing an issue with sites hosted by Akamai. From time to time we can't load some websites from Akamai and the server return "404 not found".
This is temporarily error and it could be that the same site is loaded correctly two hours later.

Has anybody an idea why this happens and maybe what we can do to avoid this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Sinu

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to talk to Akamai support. It is likely part of their defense. We had same issue with another provider and they would give 500 error to a suspected offender. We were able resolve it by adjusting WAF rules.